# Parent Child relationship visualization, pattern matching and full text searching

Tags: python, elasticsearch, neo4j, kibana

I have a dataset like below:

```
Parent  ID    Path      GrandParent  GrandParentID   Child  ModPath 
John    100   home\123  Matt         50              Ian      Ian\123
John    100   home\123  Matt         50              Andrew   Andrew\123
John    100   home\123  Matt         50              Danny    Danny\123
```

How can I best represent my data in Kibana/elasticsearch to show this parent child structure for each event? Ideally, I would like to classify this set above as a single event like I can below in Python Pandas with groupby.

```
Parent  ID    Path      GrandParent  GrandParentID   Child    ModPath 
John    100   home\123  Matt         50              Ian      Ian\123
                                                     Andrew   Andrew\123
                                                     Danny    Danny\123
```

If kibana/elasticsearch isnt the best method/toolset to use, would there be any other toolsets/methods you could recommend for visualization and referencing that is opensource?

Ideally, I would like to be able to search for the parent, child or grandparent and show all relations and properties of relations visually and or in a table.

Python was a tag that was used due to the reference to pandas.

Comment: Are all patterns in your data only 3 generations, and with similar cardinality (1 grandparent, 1 parent, multiple children)?

Comment: The chain can go many ways, such as a full lineage 20 steps out or more.

Comment: In that case, how do you want the grouping to work when it's a tree of lineages rather than a case where there's only multiple leaf nodes? Are you looking for a query that works locally, using the search term to match to the parent, and from there just getting the grandparent(s) and children? If not, please give us some desired sample output from a more complex data model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neo4j is great at pattern matching and relationship visualization. ElasticSearch is better with full text search, but Neo4j should be able to handle that adequately enough with some minor changes.

Here's an example of how to model and query this in Neo4j, and the tabular and graphical results of the query. You can use this to compare to other answers, and other solutions you try out.

For now let's model these as :Person nodes, with :CHILD relationships between them.

You haven't hinted at the data extending further than these three generations, so for now let's say that all structures in the db follow this pattern.

In Cypher, let's create the nodes in your sample graph:

```
create (matt:Person{name:'Matt', ID:50})
create (john:Person{name:'John', ID:100, path:'home/123'})
create (ian:Person{name:'Ian', path:'Ian/123'})
create (andrew:Person{name:'Andrew', path:'Andrew/123'})
create (danny:Person{name:'Danny', path:'Danny/123'})

create (matt)-[:CHILD]->(john)
create (john)-[:CHILD]->(ian)
create (john)-[:CHILD]->(andrew)
create (john)-[:CHILD]->(danny)
```

Next let's make sure there's a lowercase version of their names to take advantage of index lookups:

```
match (p:Person)
set p.lowerName = lower(p.name)
```

Then we'll add the index on lowerName so any future matches on it are quick:

```
create index on :Person(lowerName)
```

And we're ready to make a query.

Here we're using a hard-coded lowercase `lookup`, but in an actual version you'd have `lookup` be a parameter, and run `lower()` on it to get it into lowercase before the match.

```
with 'ian' as lookup
// find the grandparent root node
match (:Person{lowerName:lookup})<-[:CHILD*0..]-(grandparent)
where size ((grandparent)<-[:CHILD]-()) = 0
with grandparent
match p=(grandparent)-[:CHILD]->(parent)-[:CHILD]->(child)
return parent.name as Parent, parent.ID as ID, parent.path as Path,
       grandparent.name as GrandParent, grandparent.ID as GrandParentID, 
       collect(child {Child:child.name, ModPath:child.path}) as children, 
       collect(p) as path
```

This will work no matter which name you use in the query. It will return one row per each grandfather + parent pair, and all of that parent's children. Collecting the matched paths to the children ensures a graphical view of results is available despite the projections.

You can of course perform the projections differently, depending on the data you want to expose, or simply return the nodes directly, which will include all of their properties.

Here's the result rows and columns (ignoring the path column):
[image]

Here's the graphical view of the results:
[image]

Comment: This looks great and I think it would be great, as I am unfamiliar with how neo4j works, is the creation able to happen via import? I have thousands of csv files containing datasets that would need to be ingested as such.

Comment: Yes, Neo4j has [several means of importing CSV](https://neo4j.com/developer/guide-import-csv/), from the import tool to loading directly via Cypher using LOAD CSV.

Answer (score 0):

Elastic Search has innerhits feature to enclose parents and children as required in result. If this result is fed to neo4j you will have visual as intended